# change LinkButton style attribute from javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, css

I want to change `style` `attribute` of `linkbutton` through `javascript`
the javascript, tried working for `DropDownList` but not for `linkbutton`.

Here is my code

```
            </asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="vikas" Value="0">

            </asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnSave" Style="display: none" Text="Save" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnCancel" Style="display: none" Text="Cancel" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
        <asp:TextBox ID="lnkbtnTest" Style="display: none" Text="hope" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnChangeHR" Text="Change Hiring Manager:" runat="server"
            OnClientClick="javascript:return Visible(this.id);"></asp:LinkButton>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        alert('dil sambhal ja jara');

        function Visible(me) {
            alert(document.getElementById(me.replace("lnkbtnChnageHR", "lnkbtnTest")));
            document.getElementById(me.replace("lnkbtnChangeHR", "ddlHiringManager")).style.display = 'inline';
            document.getElementById(me.replace("lnkbtnChnageHR", "lnkbtnSave")).style.display = 'inline';
            document.getElementById(me.replace("lnkbtnChnageHR", "lnkbtnCancel")).style.display = 'inline';
            document.getElementById(me.replace("lnkbtnChnageHR", "lnkbtnChnageHR")).style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById(me.replace("lnkbtnChnageHR", "lnkbtnSave")).style.color = "#f6f6f6";
            document.getElementById(me.replace("lnkbtnChnageHR", "lnkbtnCancel")).style.color = "#f6f6f6";
            document.getElementById(me.replace("lnkbtnChnageHR", "lnkbtnTest")).style.display = 'inline';
            alert(document.getElementById(me.replace("lnkbtnChnageHR", "lnkbtnCancel")).style.display == 'none');
            return false;
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: please let me know in case question is not clear

Comment: vikas, I think you have to use CliendID to get get ASP.Net controls like `<=% lnkbtnTest.ClientID %> ` or specify `ClientIDMode="Static"` on ASP.Net controls if you are using .Net framework 4.0 or higher more on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx

Comment: got the solution thanks Habib, it was the PICNIC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys it was the PICNIC

it was the lnkbtnChangeHR not lnkbtnChnageHR